# Accessing file properties from a Request in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, file, request

Below given is the request array while submitting a form with a file and some texts.

```
array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "jcM4LprgOI9Vx9JzcFUE0rUMXxRVHGe8XgOm4CcH"
  "name" => "Some1"
  "email" => "some@gmail.com"
  "description" => "Just description."
  "birth_year" => "1287"
  "file_upload" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1214 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Skin Infections.pdf"
    -mimeType: "application/pdf"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\xampp_php8\tmp"
    filename: "phpDC93.tmp"
    basename: "phpDC93.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\xampp_php8\tmp\phpDC93.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "C:\xampp_php8\tmp\phpDC93.tmp"
    aTime: 2021-11-02 21:59:01
    mTime: 2021-11-02 21:59:00
    cTime: 2021-11-02 21:59:00
    inode: 15199648742567782
    size: 53388
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\xampp_php8\tmp\phpDC93.tmp"
  }
]
```

For getting the common File methods I can always refer to the UploadFile class from Symfony. link: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php

But how do I directly access the -originalName or size or executable property of the file_upload key?

Comment: Please don't post API keys or tokens. If the `"_token" =>` is in fact a real token or API key (as opposed to something random you made up), you can [edit] your question and flag it for moderator attention. See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258070/16886597) for more information.

Comment: Well @cocomac, thnx for mentioning but this project is running on a local server and the _token is just the CSRF token which laravel sent for validating this particular POST request.

Answer (score 0):

For Accessing it directly you can use Laravel files

Ex:-

```
// get image from request
$image = $request->file('file_upload'); 
// get original name
$name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
// get original extension
$ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Abhishek, thnx for trying but u have stated the obvious, that is how the file will be accessed but I wanted to know how will I access linkTarget property or -originalName property from the file_upload key.

Comment: For that I have updated my answer.  You can go with "getClientOriginalName()" for name and "getClientOriginalExtension"  for extension.
Thanks